# Can a range-based for loop take a type argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, static

From what I can tell, range-based for loops can only take a c-style array, an object of a type that has the member functions `begin()` and `end()` defined, or an object of a type `Type` for which the free functions `begin(Type)` and `end(Type)` can be found with ADL.

Is there a way to make the loop take a type argument, so code like this compiles?

```
class StaticVec{
//shortened implementation
    static myIterator begin();
    static myIterator end();
};

void foo() {
    for(auto elem : StaticVec){
       dosomething(elem);
    }
}
```

I would like to omit the necessity of writing `StaticVec::values()` in the loop.

Comment: Whoops. It was pseudo-code I just typed in the browser. Changed it.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you absolutely need to do what you need to do this way? I'm having trouble understanding why you need to loop through elements within a **type**. Why would a **type** have elements?

Comment: If you want a static vector, define a vector and use keyword `static` on the variable declaration... rather than building it into a new type that won't play nicely with anything else

Comment: @Nard I'm writing a library that provides scoped enum like functionality,  including easier definition of enums that are supposed to be used as bitwise flags, string conversion. One of the requested features was the ability to iterate over all elements of the enumeration, which is something I do anyway in the implementation. The functionality is there, I just thought it would look nice if one could use a range based for loop to do this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb that name was just meant as an example, I found it very descriptive of what the type would be to the `for` loop.

Comment: @iFreilicht Could you explain why there is a need to iterate through the enumeration? Perhaps elaborate on the `dosomething` function in your example?

Comment: @Nard When you define an enumeration that is supposed to hold binary flags, it will take on values that are a combination of those flags. If you convert that value to a string, it should get a representation like "move|jump". To make that possible, I have to iterate over all possible values and binary AND them with the value I try to convert. If the result of that operation is not zero, that flag is set and a lookup for the string representation of the flag is performed. All results for all set flags appended together with a "|" in between them are then the final result of the conversion.

Comment: @iFreilicht I believe I have the answer to your problem, and it doesn't involve using a range-based for loop on a type. The problem is it's a totally different question from this question so I don't think I can post it here?

Comment: @iFreilicht I just realised. Why would an enumeration have more than one value at a time? The very definition of **to enumerate** is to specify **one by one**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67064/discussion-between-ifreilicht-and-nard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general solution you can define

```
template< class Type > struct Static_collection {};

template< class Type >
auto begin( Static_collection<Type> const& )
    -> decltype( Type::begin() )
{ return Type::begin(); }


template< class Type >
auto end( Static_collection<Type> const& )
    -> decltype( Type::end() )
{ return Type::end(); }
```

and then you can write e.g.

```
auto main() -> int
{
    for( auto elem : Static_collection<Static_vec>() )
    {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

---

**Addendum:**
In most practical cases it will however suffice to just create an instance of the class holding the static `begin` and `end` member functions, as shown in Jarod42’s and Matt McNabb’s answers (the former already posted when I posted the above), e.g.

```
for( auto const& elem : StaticVec() )
{
    // ...
}
```

If instance creation can have undesirable side effects, now or perhaps after some future maintainance work, then use the general solution.

Otherwise, if instance creation is essentially free, I’d go for that.

Comment: I wanted to ask why you make it so complicated, but you explained that under MattMcNabbs answer. Maybe you'd want to add that here? Just a short note that this is the way to go when you don't want to create an instance. (Which is fortunately possible in my case)

Answer (score 4):

You may still (if applicable) construct a dummy object:

```
for (auto&& elem : StaticVec{}) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make as much semantic sense in my case, but apart from the `::values()` thing I already mentioned, this may be the only other way.
So is your answer to the question "No, that's not possible"?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not possible. The range variable in your example is `StaticVec` (which is not a variable) so the code it expands to would involve either `auto it = StaticVec.begin()` or `auto it = begin(StaticVec)` and neither of those expressions is valid, the function calls require an object not a type.

Answer (score 1):

This works because static member functions can still be called via `.` notation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct StaticVec
{
    typedef int *myIterator;
    static int x[5];
    static myIterator begin() { return x; }
    static myIterator end() { return x + 5; }
};

int StaticVec::x[5] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

void dosomething(int i)
{
cout << i << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    for(auto elem : StaticVec())
    {
       dosomething(elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it creates an instance, which might have undesirable side effects. I.e. it's not a general solution. I already provided a general solution, but for any given special case the above would be the practical default choice if applicable (I didn't discuss it, should perhaps have done?, anyway already mentioned in [Jarod42's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27502632/464581) when I wrote my answer, I think).